# Command-line Number of thread per process on MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, process, threads

I'd like to be able to get the number of thread per process in command-line and get the exact same number I can see via the Activity Monitor.

At the moment the IntelliJ IDEA process (PID 5235) has 266 Thread. I'd like to get this number but via a command line.

I've tried

```
lsof -p 5235 | wc -l
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: lsof lists open files so it would not provide you with the threads

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NUM=`ps M <pid> | wc -l` && echo $((NUM-1))
```

We subtract 1 from the line count because `ps` outputs a HEADER in the 1st line.

Comment: (1) The output from `wc -l` is a single “word”; i.e., a (*single* ) non-null sequence of non-blank characters, possibly preceded and/or followed by whitespace.  What do you gain by piping it into `xargs`?  (I.e., won’t your command do the same thing if you leave off the `| xargs`?)  Are you doing it just to strip the leading and/or trailing whitespace?  Why bother?  `expr` will take care of that for you.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Why are you subtracting one?  To exclude the header line from the count?  Good answers explain things like that. (3) I suppose using `expr` is OK, but it might be better to say `NUM=$((NUM-1))` or `((NUM--))`. Or you could just suppress the header by saying `ps M -opid= <pid>`.

Comment: @Scott: you're absolutely right. I did update the answer to include the your improvements. Thank you! The only thing I didn't include was the `-opid=` because it doesn't seem to work on macOS. If you still feel it could be better, feel free to update it or just leave another comment.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
ps M <pid> | wc -l
```

Comment: As discussed in the comments under [jweyrich’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/753682/150988#753707), this will be too high by one, because it will count the `ps` header line.  Or do you have a rationale for believing that your answer is correct?

Answer (score 2):

One can also engage `tail` command in order to cut off header line in the `ps M` output, e.g:

```
ps M <pid> | tail -n+2 | wc -l
```

where `-n+2` option means "get all lines starting from the second one"