# How to count the total number of threads used on Mac in command line?

Tags: macos, threads, macos-bigsur

[Command-line Number of thread per process on MacOS](https://superuser.com/questions/753682/command-line-number-of-thread-per-process-on-macos)

This question is about the thread of a process. I want to get the total number of threads on Mac. Can anybody show me the command to get this number?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command in Mac that does this. Type ‘top’ in the terminal. Then, every second it refreshes the thread number and all the processes it runs and all the specific information. Use:

top -s (number)

to specify that it refreshes every (number) seconds.